# How can I completely clean out the IOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have several image data files in my app in development.

I deleted some of the files from the APP in XCODE (moved to trash). I check the project in Finder and the old files are gone.

I did reset contents and settings on the simulator.

I rerun the app in the similar and the old files are STILL there.

If I replace X with new X, new X is there.
If I remove Y and replace with nothing, Y is still there.

How can I get rid of the old files?

Comment: Thanks for the help.

It turned out that I have to do BOTH reset the simulator and PRODUCT CLEAN.

If I did either on its own, the old files kept coming back. Both, together, did it.

Answer (score 15):

Here you can completely clean out your iOS simulator :

1. First run your project
2. When pops up the simulator, select it
3. Then go to `iOS Simulator` section from the upper left menu and select it
4. Then select `Reset Content and Settings` from the drop down menu

   [image]
5. An alert message should pops up with this message "Are you sure you want to reset the iOS Simulator content and settings?", Select `Reset` there.

   [image]

Then wait for a while and clean your xcode by pressing `shift + command + k`

By doing this your project should be cleaned. If you want to Delete your "Stored Simulator File" by yourself, then :

1. Go to Desktop first
2. Select `Go` from the upper menu & hold `option` button
3. Now the `Library` option should come in the drop down list then go to the following directory from there

`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/`

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`Clean` the project from the `Product` menu

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode you need to go
`Product>Clean`

and if that doesn't work hold down <kbd>option</kbd> and choose
`Product>Clean Build Folder`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably clean your project. This happens often.

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to clean the project and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to clean the build directory. Or you can do both from the Product menu of Xcode - just hold <kbd>Option</kbd> key to show the clean build option in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Visit ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
Drop all the folders in there and you'll be good to go!